# normal bars positioning on d3.js bar chart

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I try to make a bar chart on the basis of 2D data array (I din`t want to use 2D array initially, so there is a function  "mergingAr", which merges them) using d3.js. Here is the code:

```
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

    var arr1 = [399200,100000, 352108, 600150, 39000, 17005, 4278];
    var arr2 = [839, 149, 146, 200, 200, 121, 63];

function mergingAr (array1, array2)
{
    var i, out = [];//literal new array
    for(i=0;i<array1.length;i++)
    {
        out.push([array1[i],array2[i]]);
    }
    return out;
}

var data = mergingAr(arr1, arr2);
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


   var x = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { 
          return d[0]; })])
          .range([0, width]);


   var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
      .range([height, 0]);


var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")


  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
      //.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("width", width/a1.length)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d[1]); });
```

Te problem is - the bars cover each other, there are no distance between them, even if I used rangeRoundBands.

Comment: Try `.attr("width", x.rangeBand()/2)`.

Comment: Hm, here is another problem: "Uncaught TypeError: Object function i(n){return o(n)} has no method 'rangeBand'"

Comment: Ah, for this, you need to use an ordinal scale, not a linear one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your code.

The first one is that the data array is not sorted. In order to sort it you can do:

```
out = out.sort(function(a,b) { return d3.ascending(a[0],b[0]) })
```

before returning `out` in your `mergeAt` function. Sorting the array makes sure that you process bars in the right order.

The second issue is that your intervals are not equal. To remediate to this, I made the width of a block equal to the distance to the next one (but you might want to do something different):

```
.attr("width", function(d,i){
    if(i!=(data.length-1)) {
        return x(data[i+1][0])-x(data[i][0])
    } else {
        return 10; // the last block is of width 10. a cleaner way is to add a 
                   // marker at the end of the array to know where to finish 
                   // the axis
    }
})
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/6WJPA/

---

## Edit

In order to have the same interval between each bar and the same width, you have to change the scale to an ordinal one:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1)
    .domain(data.map(function(d){return d[0]}))
```

Then, you need to change the way you compute the width to:

```
.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/6WJPA/2/

Comment: Thank you. But how can I get bars with equal width and interval between them like [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304). When I try to do this:
`var x = d3.scale.ordinal().domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return d[0];})]).rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);`  -- it gives me strange results: x-axis with two values (0 and 600150) and one lonely bar.

Comment: You just have to change the width to `.attr("width", x.rangeBand())`. See the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/6WJPA/2/)